# Why does the person who wants to cancel an appointment say キャンセルさせてください to his/her partner?

Tags: grammar, politeness

Assume A has a partner named B. Last week both made an appointment to have dinner (dating). For a certain reason, A cannot come for the appointment and calls B by phone saying

> ・・・キャンセルさせてください。　Please make me cancel ...

### Question

A wants to cancel the appointment, but why does A ask B to make A cancel it as if the source of problem is on B's side? I think A should say

> ・・・キャンセルしてください。　Please cancel ...

Comment: If A cancels, does B also need to cancel?  Can A cancel just his/her own attendance

Comment: Isn't it 'please **let** me cancel' rather than 'please **make** me cancel'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works like "Please let me", so

> キャンセルさせてください = Please let me cancel [our appointment]

(It wouldn't be interpreted as "Please make me cancel [our appointment]".)

You could also say

> キャンセルしてください = Please cancel [our appointment]

but it is a lot more direct (and thus less polite).

Answer (score 0):

I want to expand @Earthliŋ's above very good answer, but it will not fit in a comment so I place it here.

使役形 itself is not 謙譲語 or 丁寧語, but it softens a request and is often used together with 謙譲語 or 丁寧語.

**謙譲語**

If you are asking politely to be allowed to use a toilet you could say

トイレを使わせて頂けませんか？（使役形＋謙譲語）

However, without 使役形,  謙譲語  would be unacceptable

*NG トイレを使って頂けませんか？（終止形＋謙譲語）*

***丁寧語***

A more direct way to ask to use the toilet by formulating with  使役形

トイレを使わせて下さい。　（使役形＋丁寧語）

However, with 丁寧語, 使役形 is not required as in:

トイレを使うことができますか？　 （丁寧語）

トイレを使っても良いですか？ 　（丁寧語）

There are 使役形＋丁寧語 formulations which are not allowed as in:

*NG　トイレを使わせますか？ （使役形＋丁寧語）*

*NG　トイレを使わせることはできますか？ （使役形＋丁寧語）*

*NG　トイレを使わせてもいいですか？ （使役形＋丁寧語）*

Comment: 「使わ」は未然形ですけど、「使わ**せ** （る・て・ます）」って、「未然形」じゃなくて「使役形」とかになるんじゃないですかね・・例えば「使わせます」は`未然形＋丁寧語`ではなく「使役形+丁寧語」とか「(動詞の)未然形+使役の助動詞+丁寧の助動詞」とかになるのでは？